# Admob won't work

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services

I try to implement Admob in the Goceng project. Since Admob changed, I can't really follow the documentation of this project.

My error is

```
05-04 12:51:21.959: W/Ads(9017): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
```

Many other people bought this project too, so I think the code is written well, I did not changed anything.

For testing I use:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("XXX").build();
ads.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Admob id looks like

```
<string name="admob_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

I just created an App in Admob and an advertisement block where I have this ID from.

Can anyone tell me my mistake?

Meta-data etc. in manifest is there, as I mentioned it is a finished project which works for many people

**Code:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ctx = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Declare object of Utils class;
        utils = new Utils(this);

        // connect view objects and xml ids
        adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);


        // add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                     .add(R.id.frame_content, fragObjList).commit();

        // load ads
         Ads.loadAds(adView);

    }
```

activity_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post more code? It's hard to say based on what you posted.

Comment: see my edit, hope it's what you wanted

Comment: does your `AdView` XML in `activity_home.xml` or in the `Fragment` layout?

Comment: It's in the xml, not in the fragment layout

Comment: can you post `activity_home.xml`?

Comment: Post more of your log. A few lines before and after the error.